# Fitting discrete points on a normal distribution

Tags: distributions, python, excel, curve-fitting, discrete-data

I have an ordinal ranking of 16 objects. I know that the value of the first object is 0, the second value is 2, and the last object is 14. I'd like to map each of the intermediate objects to an integer value (between 0 and 14), along the lines of a rounded value of some normal distribution. I'm not sure about what the variance is, so ideally I'd like a formula that I can analyze the various family of curves (defined by some input variance) that are defined by these criteria to see which one fits the best.

I know that I've possibly been vague, but I'm not sure on what else to include, so feel free to ask for any clarification.

Ideally I'd like an Excel/Python solution, as I'm not really familiar with R/Mathematica/Octave.

Answer (score 3):

What's missing here includes why you want to do this.

In terms of how to map integer ordinal data to something more like a normal distribution:

Your ranks here range from 0 to 14. (rank + 0.5) / 15 produces a scale that ranges from 1/30 to 29/30 and so treats extreme ranks symmetrically (there are other ways to do that). You could plug those fractions into NORMSINV() in MS Excel.

Those numbers will be approximately normally distributed if the ranks are uniformly distributed, which is a big "if". In old literature they are called rankits, normal scores, etc.

I see no point in further rounding to integers. That could separate points that are very close indeed, or round numbers together that are different. Such rounding would not be reversible.

If this seems quite off target, my advice is to tell us more about your data and your real scientific or practical problem. People asking advice here who don't know much statistics often think they should abstract out the concrete details and make their question as statistical as possible, but the opposite can be true.

(UPDATE) The best way to assess (approximation to) normality is to use a normal probability plot. What's above is irrelevant to that. I don't use Excel enough  to advise on how to do it. I've never used Python. But, but, but: your data are integers and there are, it seems, at most only 15 distinct values, so the approximation can't be anything but crude.

Comment: Essentially, I have ordinal rankings of what I believe to be the ordering of some Dota 2 (type of computer game) teams, playing in a tournament. I did a large Monte Carlo simulation using their historical results. The teams were split into two groups and are playing round robin within the groups. I think that the results will be somewhat normally distributed, so 1 team will have max points (14) and one will have min points (0), so I want to see how my ordinal prediction map into actual overall score.

And I didn't want to go into too much detail because I didn't think it's *that relevant.

Comment: The details are highly relevant, Noxville, because the little information you have supplied suggests your data should be neither normally distributed nor independent. It looks like you may be forcing on them a model that gives bad information. Many in this community feel it would be remiss to give you a good solution to the question you asked when there is so much evidence that it will do more harm than good; we would rather understand what your *real* problem is so we can give you answers that actually help you out.